# Printing GLSL shader info log in D

Tags: opengl, shader, d

I have a shader that does not compile. I want to print its info log, but get only "?" symbols instead of the log. Here's the printing code:

```
    GLint shaderCompiled = GL_FALSE;
    glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shaderCompiled );

    if (shaderCompiled != GL_TRUE)
    {
        char[1000] errorLog;
        auto info = errorLog.ptr;
        glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, 1000, null, info );
        writeln( errorLog );
    }
```

I'm using DerelictSDL2 and OpenGL 3.3 on OS X Mavericks with Nvidia GT 750M. I can print info logs in programs written in C++ on the same setup so maybe I'm using D language wrong.

Comment: Solved. I was calling glGetShaderInfoLog also for GL_LINK_STATUS when I should have called glGetProgramInfoLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I was calling glGetShaderInfoLog also for GL_LINK_STATUS when I should have called glGetProgramInfoLog.